# If the product name is nil then use another name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently developing a cart which will take the id of the CD or a DVD, it then gets the name of the item.

If I use them individually it works fine as I have made the relevant changes in the other files.

The code currently is:

```
<% if line_item==@current_item %>
  <tr id='current_item'>
<% else %>  
  <tr>
<% end %>
    <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
    <td><%= line_item.product.name %></td>
    <td><%= line_item.dvd.name %></td>

    <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price, :unit=>'&pound') %></td>
  </tr>
```

If I have a `<td><%= line_item.cd.name %></td>` line and only add CDs it works fine, and vice-versa with this line `<td><%= line_item.dvd.name %></td>`.

What I want is it to do a test to see if `cd.name` is `nil` and if it is use the `dvd.name`, but this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
 line_item.cd.try(:name) || line_item.dvd.try(:name)
```

This code will first try to get CD name and fallback to DVD if either `cd` or `cd.name` is nil.

Answer (score -1):

In your `Item` model, try adding this method:

```
def cd_or_dvd
  line_item.dvd || line_item.cd
end
```

Than in the view:

```
<td><%= line_item.dvd.name %></td>
```